# Big Query authentication

Tags: r, google-oauth, google-bigquery

I have a R script which calls Big Query API and then executes some queries. It works fine if I start this script using batch file. However when I try to start script as System, I see that (more likely) it can't log into bigquery. Maybe it is so because BQ autontification file (.httr-oauth) is valid for my user< not SYSTEM.

The info in .httr-oauth file is hashed so I can't change user (if there is info aboust user there). Maybe there is some way one can make another .httr-oauth file for system? Or is another error i bumped into?

Comment: What error message does R throw in this case? I suspect that when running as SYSTEM R is loading .httr-oauth from a different location and is just not finding the file. From an auth perspective, BigQuery doesn't care where your credentials are located, only that they are provided. So there's nothing preventing you from giving a copy of user A's credentials to user B and letting user B make BigQuery api calls *as* user A.

Comment: Michael, .httr-oauth is in the working directory and it's location surely doesn't depend on user. Actually it was pretty complicated for me to start batch as system interactively (I used PsExec). Nevertheless there all I have for debugging is my own log file and I see no errors see (even thow I use sink), it just stops somewhere the autentification to bigquery begins.